# Why response.body() its null?

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit

Im using retrofit to send a a json object to the server, im trying to create a user, im sending this json object
`{"apellido":"prueba","email":"prueba@hotmail.com","fechaDeNacimiento":"11/29/1998","formaDeRegistro":"Android","nombre":"prueba","password":"12345678","username":"prueba"}`

In this example i create a invalid user , so the server response with a json object where code its the code error and message its the explication of the error

```
[{"code":"5","message":"The email is in use"}]
```

Interface

```
public interface UserClient {


@POST("usuarios")
Call<Usuarios> create(@Body Usuarios usuario);
```

}

Data model

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Usuarios {

@SerializedName("username")
String username;
@SerializedName("email")
String email;
@SerializedName("password")
String password;
@SerializedName("nombre")
String nombre;
@SerializedName("apellido")
String apellido;
@SerializedName("fechaDeNacimiento")
String fechaDeNacimiento;
@SerializedName("formaDeRegistro")
String formaDeRegistro;

 String message;


public Usuarios(String email, String username, String password, String nombre, String apellido, String fechaDeNacimiento, String formaDeRegistro){
    this.username=username;
    this.email=email;
    this.password=password;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido= apellido;
    this.fechaDeNacimiento = fechaDeNacimiento;
    this.formaDeRegistro = formaDeRegistro;
}

public String getMessage(){
    return message;
}
```

}

and Retrofit implement

```
 OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpClientBuilder=new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggin=new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggin.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    okhttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggin);
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://intense-lake-39874.herokuapp.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okhttpClientBuilder.build());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();


    UserClient service = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);
    Call<Usuarios> call = service.create(usuario);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Usuarios>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Usuarios> call, Response<Usuarios> response) {

            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Usuario Registrado! "+response.body().getMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Usuarios> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Algo fallo..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

So  i can see the logcat response but in the body its appoint to null, how i can acces to the "message"?

[This is the logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pMwc.png)

Comment: You can use `response.body().getMessage` instead of `response.body().getmessage`

Comment: Yes, i use that but as i said , the body its appoint to null, so the app crash

Comment: Could you show your crash log for it ?

Comment: Sure give me one second

Comment: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html

Comment: Check if the status code is 200 or 201 else your response body will be null

Comment: I update the logcat i dont know if it the JSON object as response.. normally a json object star with keys.. but in this case that star with brackets

Comment: diegoveloper you are rigth , i create a valid user and the message its display correctly now , but for example if it is an error and  i want to show the message adquired by the server in the respond object .. what should i do?

Comment: My answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is because your response is not successful therefore you need to parse the error body, try with this code:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) { 
// Do your success stuff...
 } else
 { 
try 
{ 
JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
 Toast.makeText(getContext(), jObjError.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } catch (Exception e) {
 Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
}
```

Of course that you can use another parser like Gson .